# Stripe Cancel one payment in subscription?

Tags: stripe-payments, subscription

Is it possible in a [Stripe](https://stripe.com) recurring/subscription to cancel one debit/charge (I.e The customer shouldn't be charged for one month/week/day etc).

Eg: Month 1, Stripe debits customer.
Month 2, Customer has decided service isn't required so we need to avoid debit this month.
Month 3, Stripe debits customer.

I've checked stripe docs and it only seems to mention completely cancelling the subscription, and getting the customer to re-subscribe which isn't very affective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple options you could choose to credit the customer:

One would be to create an invoice item with a negative amount. This would apply a credit to the next upcoming invoice.

Another option would be to edit the `account_balance` of the customer, this would deducted upon the next subscription charge.

https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_invoiceitem

https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_customer